# CSS Font Smoothing similar to Photoshop "Smooth" Option

Tags: html, css, fonts, smoothing

I'm trying to replicate the photoshop font "Smooth" option using HTML/CSS. Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Here is the text in Photoshop:  (20 px Tahoma Smooth)

[image]

Here is the same text in HTML: (20 px Tahoma)

[image]

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use webkit fonts to have more control over your text.

Font anti-aliasing is handled by the rendered not the code unfortunately. The OS and/or browser in this case.

I recommend checking out [Typekit](https://typekit.com/fonts), [Fonts.com](http://www.fonts.com/) or [Google Fonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts) to explore some options here. If you have the font licenses something like [cufon](http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/) may also be a good idea.